# awk count number of matches more or less than in column from two files

Tags: bash, awk

I want to match $1 from one file to $1 to another and then count the number of matches that lie between `$2(File1) < $2(File2) <$3(File1)` and do this for each match

**File 1** segments

```
Chromosome  Start   End Value
chr1    0   121347754   -0.009727287106215954
chr1    144009053   249250621   0.18180939555168152
chr2    0   90278124    -0.0197499617934227
chr2    95387134    243199373   -0.009399870410561562
chr3    0   91000000    -0.015508042648434639
chr3    93541117    198022430   0.011255052872002125
chr4    0   49064792    -0.02086501568555832
chr4    52700771    143350756   0.013872206211090088
chr4    143350756   191154276   -0.004134085960686207
```

**File 2** probes

```
Chromosome  Start   End Value   Array
chr1    798959  798959  1.0 0
chr1    1048955 1048955 0.0 0
chr1    1158277 1158277 0.0 0
chr1    1314015 1314015 0.5307189226150513  0
chr1    1489928 1489928 0.45127609372138977 0
chr1    1499298 1499298 1.0 0
chr1    1948400 1948400 0.0 0
chr1    2021114 2021114 0.0 0
chr1    2056735 2056735 0.0 0
```

so the output would be:

```
$1(matching both File 1 and 2) $2(File1) $3(File1) $4(number of matches)
```

**Output**

```
Chromosome  Start   End Probes
chr1    0   121347754   238
chr1    144009053   249250621   590
chr2    0   90278124    321
```

I have been trying to do this with awk and it's not working!

This is as far as I have gotten

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1 FS $2;next}{ print $1[File1] "\t" $2[File1] "\t" $3[File1] "\t" $2[File1] < $2[File2] < $3[File1]  }' File1 File2
```

Comment: What's your expected output given this sample data? Can you show what you've got so far, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1 FS a[$2];next}{ print $2 < a[$2] < $3  }' 0008483_A02\ copy/snps.txt 0008483_A02\ copy/segments.txt

Comment: so the output is
$1 $2(File1) $3(File1) $4(number of matches)

form the example above it would be:
chr1    0   121347754   238
chr1    144009053   249250621   590

Comment: It's best to include the code (by editing your question) that you're working with, and either an explanation of what is not working, or actual sample output from your current code. Good luck.

Comment: @user3324491 Can you edit that information into your question? It'll be easier to read there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Chromosome  Start   End Probes"}
NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$1]==""?$2:a[$1] FS $2;next}
{ delete c 
  split(a[$1],b,FS)
  for (i=1;i<=length(b);i++)
       if (b[i]>$2&&b[i]<$3) c[$1]++
  if (c[$1])print $1,$2,$3,c[$1]
}' file2 file1
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN {print "Chromosome  Start   End Probes"}` print the title
- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$1]==""?$2:a[$1] FS $2;next}`, read file2, attach value to array a with key of $1
- `split(a[$1],b,FS)`, split array a[$1] value to array b
- `if (b[i]>$2&&b[i]<$3) c[$1]++` count it

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering though why when I add to the print statement $4 why it keeps adding a ^M newline at the end of it?

Comment: seems you need run `dos2unix yourfile yourfile` to convert the windows file to unix file

Comment: But, ^M does not appear with the original answer - `code`(if (c[$1])print $1,$2,$3,c[$1]) but does with `code`(if (c[$1])print $1,$2,$3,c[$1],$4). There is no ^M present in either of the .txt files I am using so something about that line and calling $4 either within the loop is adding this ^M but I'm not sure why or how to avoid it as I would rather tackle it now then just use sed or dos2unix to get rid of it.

Comment: can you run the command on your original files:  `cat -A file1` and `cat -A file2` and check if  ^M in there or not?

Comment: you're right, it was hiding in one of the files and didn't show when I used opened them with vi